# Mocking statement when the input parameter of method as exception

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm writing Junit test case for the below scenario and need some suggestions to cover the below snippet:

```
ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(new InvalidInputException("Ethernet Ring Name not found"),methodName);
```

I tried passing `ringName` as null or empty but not sure how to mock exception block. Can someone please give a suggestion?

```
public void deleteEthernetRing(String ringName, String userID) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Delete Ethernet Ring ");
    String methodName = "Delete Ethernet Ring ";
    ResponsePayLoad returnVal = new ResponsePayLoad();
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ringName))
        // NOT COVERED
        ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(new InvalidInputException("Ethernet Ring Name not found"),methodName);
    if (userID == null || userID.isEmpty()) {
        ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(new InvalidInputException("UserID Must be provided to remove Ring"),methodName);
    } else {
        // The actual business logic 
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `manageException` method do? It rethrows some wrapped exception or maybe it handles exception, throws nothing and returns void?

Comment: if this is static method, you need power mock

Comment: You probably want to test the effect of `manageException`, rather than just checking that it gets called.  Strictly speaking, this makes your test an integration test, rather than a unit test; but for a small static method, that's probably OK.

Comment: I would suggest you refactor to inject the dependency on the error handling utility. That would make it trivial to mock the error handling utility to verify that `manageException` is being called correctly.

Comment: You might want to add the full method you try to test and the test you have written so far. What I see here currently does not seem to need mocking, but it depends on what `ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException` is actually doing. So you might want to add this method (class) as well.

Comment: It is printing error and rethrows InvalidInputException.Here is my complete method.

Comment: @michalk you are right .It just re-throws error.I have updated in the description.Can you please suggest

Comment: @Naresh note that if you have a method which always throws an exception, if you declare the return type to be something Throwable (i.e. some exception or error), you can use `throw ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(...);`. This tells the compiler that execution will not continue after that statement.

Comment: @AndyTurner It will not throw error always.Only error throws when input is null.

Answer (score 0):

As `@AndyTurner` pointed out the answer to your question is related on how you declare a method and how code coverage is measured.

Check the Utils class below for 2 version of (basically) the same method.

```
static class Utils {

    public static void handleException1(Exception e) throws Exception {
        throw e;
    }

    public static Exception handleException2(Exception e) {
        return e;
    }
}
```

---

```
static class Example1 {
    public boolean test(boolean flag) throws Exception {
        if (flag) {
            Utils.handleException1(new Exception());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Executing `Example1.test(true)` with a 'code coverage tool' leads to the line with the `handleException` method marked as not covered.

---

```
static class Example2 {
    public boolean test(boolean flag) throws Exception {
        if (flag) {
            throws Utils.handleException2(new Exception());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Executing `Example2.test(true)` with a 'code coverage tool' leads to the line marked as covered.

---

As `@AndyTurner` pointed out, the reason for that is that in `Example1` the 'compiler' / 'code coverage tool' does not know that the method `handleException1` will never return. It expects that such a path exists and therefore does not mark this line as covered.

In `Example2` it sees the `throws` keyword and knows that if this point in the code the method ends here. Therefore all possible pathes are covered.

---

Whether or not you want (or need) to mock the method is an entirely different question. But judging from your question(s) your aim was to achieve code coverage, so changing your code should solve that issue.