# How to mock exception which is passed as parameter to method

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Need pointers to cover junit for ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException line.PLease help.

```
public void deleteEthernetRing(String ringName,
        String userID) throws Exception {


    if (StringUtils.isBlank(ringName))
        ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(new InvalidInputException("Ethernet Ring Name not found"),methodName);

    if (userID == null || userID.isEmpty()) {
        ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException(new InvalidInputException("UserID Must be provided to remove Ring"),methodName);
    }

    else {
    The actual business logic 
    }
    }
```

Comment: You have posted similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264067/mocking-statement-when-the-input-parameter-of-method-as-exception) today. You should wait for an answer there...

Comment: `when(YOUR_CLASS.deleteEthernetRing(null,any())).thenThrow(new InvalidInputException());` - It should work.

Comment: What are you trying to test about this code? What do you want to mock, and why?

Comment: we need 100% code coverage .But this exception statement is showing as not covered.I have added below code.                                                             
        
  
  Mockito.when(
    crudRingConnectionNodeService.deleteEthernetRing(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenThrow( new DeviceNotFoundException("405",Mockito.anyString()));
  
  

   try {
    controller.deleteEthernetRing(null,"userID");
   
  } catch (Exception ex)
  {
   Assert.assertEquals("Ethernet Ring Name not found", ex.getMessage());
  }
 }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mocking statement when the input parameter of method as exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264067/mocking-statement-when-the-input-parameter-of-method-as-exception)

Comment: I have added my answer to your other question. As they are the same I would suggest you just delete this one (if it doesn't get closed before that).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I believe the reason you are not able to cover exception line is because you are actually mocking `deleteEthernetRing` method in the service being actually tested, thus unit test case flow never enters this method.

If you want to cover these exception lines as well, then you would have to write test cases for `deleteEthernetRing` method as well.

If you want to achieve 100% coverage, you shall have to write at-least 4 test cases for `deleteEthernetRing` method:

> Case 1. ringName is blank.

Expected Behavior : ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException is invoked.

> Case 2. userID is null.

Expected Behavior : ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException is invoked.

> Case 3. userID is blank.

Expected Behavior : ErrorHandlingUtils.manageException is invoked.

> Case 4. ringName is not blank and userID is not blank.

Expected Behavior : No Exception: The actual business logic

Hope that helps :)

Comment: The problem is a bit different. If you're intrested read my answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57264067/mocking-statement-when-the-input-parameter-of-method-as-exception/57277984#57277984), as this is just a copy of the same question.